# Identifying the CPU architecture type using C#

Tags: c#, architecture, cpu, identify

I want to check which CPU architecture is the user running, is it
i386 or X64 or AMD64. I want to do it in C#.
I know i can try WMI or Registry. Is there any other way apart from these two?
My project targets .NET 2.0!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could also try (only works if it's not manipulated):

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
```

Comment: Not set goes to "manipulated" case (at least on Vista, it's set by default). I suggested it as an alternate way, not necessarily the best way.

Comment: I am on AMD64 and Vista 64bit and looking at the variables in the console window I see AMD64 for PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, BUT running my unit tests using ReSharper I see "x86" returned. Probably OK if the test runs in 32bit mode, BUT I use this result to decide how to launch another executable and select its 32bit version which refuses to start on 64bit os.

Comment: @romeok: This should NOT be used to detect the processor architecture of the machine. It may be used to detect the architecture the program is running on. If you want to check to see whether the OS is 64-bit you should use other methods like WMI. However the OP explicitly mentioned he wants something else.

Comment: caution: the return value depends on how the calling process was compiled (x86, x64, AnyCPU)!  
the solution is to pass a second parameter:  
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)  

also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1739055/1468842

Comment: This is Windows-specific and won't work on macOS or Linux.

Answer (score 32):

I know that this question is from the past, but as of 2017, there is now a simple method to know the architecture of the current process, in .net standard :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture
```

The value returned is one of X86, X64, ARM, ARM64 and gives the architecture of the process it's running in. `OSArchitecture` returns the architecture of the installed operating system instead.

Links to the docs (pretty useless though...):

RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.processarchitecture?view=netstandard-1.4

Architecture enumeration:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.architecture?view=netstandard-1.4

Comment: This doesn't work for x86 .NET apps running on ARM64: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456140/how-to-detect-were-running-under-the-arm64-version-of-windows-10-in-net

Comment: There is also RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture, which starting in .NET 7 it will return the correct value for X86 apps running in emulation on ARM64. https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/30894

Answer (score 29):

What led me here  is checking for a 32 vs 64 bit OS. the highest rated answer is looking at the setting for the **Current process**. After not finding an answer I found the following setting. Hope this works for you.

```
bool is64 = System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
```

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread, but as an advice to a future reader: since a 32-bit process can happily run on a 64-bit OS, `System.Environment.Is64BitProcess` was more useful in my case (set the `PATH` variable for the "correct" `sqlite3.dll` based on the architecture). The OS was indeed 64-bit in my case, but because of another library I had to compile my app as 32-bit.

Comment: Is64BitProcess didn't appear until at least version 4. For any version, I think IntPtr.Size is the most elegant solution; I wrapped a ternary expression around it in the code that brought me to this page.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a piece of code that seems to work (based on P/Invoke); It allows to determine the CPU/Machine architecture, current process architecture and also a given binary file architecture (how it's been compiled):

```
    public enum Architecture
    {
        Unknown,
        x86,
        x64,
        arm64,
    }

    public static Architecture ProcessArchitecture
    {
        get
        {
            var si = new SYSTEM_INFO();
            GetSystemInfo(ref si);
            return GetArchitecture(ref si);
        }
    }

    public static Architecture MachineArchitecture
    {
        get
        {
            var si = new SYSTEM_INFO();
            GetNativeSystemInfo(ref si);
            return GetArchitecture(ref si);
        }
    }

    public static Architecture ReadFileArchitecture(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            return ReadFileArchitecture(stream);
        }
    }

    // note .NET dll will come out as x86
    public static Architecture ReadFileArchitecture(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));

        var length = stream.Length;
        if (length < 64)
            return Architecture.Unknown;

        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        stream.Position = 60;
        var peHeaderPtr = reader.ReadUInt32();
        if (peHeaderPtr == 0)
        {
            peHeaderPtr = 128;
        }
        if (peHeaderPtr > length - 256)
            return Architecture.Unknown;

        stream.Position = peHeaderPtr;
        var peSignature = reader.ReadUInt32();
        if (peSignature != 0x00004550) // "PE"
            return Architecture.Unknown;

        var machine = reader.ReadUInt16();
        Architecture arch;
        switch (machine)
        {
            case IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64:
                arch = Architecture.x64;
                break;

            case IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386:
                arch = Architecture.x86;
                break;

            case IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64:
                arch = Architecture.arm64;
                break;

            default:
                return Architecture.Unknown;
        }
        return arch;
    }

    private static Architecture GetArchitecture(ref SYSTEM_INFO si)
    {
        switch (si.wProcessorArchitecture)
        {
            case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64:
                return Architecture.x64;

            case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM64:
                return Architecture.arm64;

            case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL:
                return Architecture.x86;

            default:
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    private const int PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 = 9;
    private const int PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL = 0;
    private const int PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_ARM64 = 12;
    private const int IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_ARM64 = 0xAA64;
    private const int IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 = 0x14C;
    private const int IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 = 0x8664;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern void GetSystemInfo(ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SYSTEM_INFO
    {
        public short wProcessorArchitecture;
        public short wReserved;
        public int dwPageSize;
        public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
        public IntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
        public int dwNumberOfProcessors;
        public int dwProcessorType;
        public int dwAllocationGranularity;
        public short wProcessorLevel;
        public short wProcessorRevision;
    }
```

This code supports x86, x64 and arm64 architectures and Windows XP. In modern versions of .NET you have built-in functions in the [System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation).

Comment: Thanks this works great... That i expect the Machine Type not the OS type.

Comment: Simon, this is by far the leanest solution offered. Everyone who's afraid of Platform Invoke, get over it; it doesn't (usually) bite!

Comment: Keep in mind, the docs for `SYSTEM_INFO` use `DWORD` and `WORD` which are both unsigned. Everything in your struct is signed.. this could cause issues if you are using any other members of this struct.

Comment: Note that `GetNativeSystemInfo` reports `AMD64` for x86 and x64 processes running emulated on an ARM64 machine.

Answer (score 6):

[Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx) WMI Class will do the job. Use [MgmtClassGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa(VS.80).aspx) to generate strongly-typed wrappers.

Comment: This is probably the best answer to the question.

Comment: how is Win32_Processor class supposed to help? if you were talking about OSArchitecture, then this property is not available on most of Windows versions, only a few latest versions support it.

Answer (score 5):

Finally the shortest trick to resolve the platform/processor architecture for the current running CLR runtime in C# is:

```
PortableExecutableKinds peKind;
ImageFileMachine machine;
typeof(object).Module.GetPEKind(out peKind, out machine);
```

Here [Module.GetPEKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an [ImageFileMachine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.imagefilemachine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration, which exists since .NET v2:

```
public enum ImageFileMachine
{
    I386    = 0x014C,
    IA64    = 0x0200,
    AMD64   = 0x8664,
    ARM     = 0x01C4    // new in .NET 4.5
}
```

Why not use `new AssemblyName(fullName)` or `typeof(object).Assembly.GetName()`?
Well there is this `HACK` comment in ASP.NET MVC source code (since 1.0):

```
private static string GetMvcVersionString() {
    // DevDiv 216459:
    // This code originally used Assembly.GetName(), but that requires FileIOPermission, which isn't granted in
    // medium trust. However, Assembly.FullName *is* accessible in medium trust.
    return new AssemblyName(typeof(MvcHttpHandler).Assembly.FullName).Version.ToString(2);
}
```

See they use some hidden tricks for themselves. Sadly, the `AssemblyName` constructor doesn't set the `ProcessorArchitecture` field appropriately, it's just `None` for whatever new AssemblyName.

So for future readers, let me recommend you using that ugly GetPEKind with ImageFileMachine!

Notes:

- This returns the current running *runtime architecture*, not the underlying system architecture!
  That said, the only exception is that an I386 runtime may run on an AMD64 system.
- Tested on mono/ubuntu 14.04/AMD64 and .NET/Win7/I386.

Comment: This is wrong - this gets x86 instead of x64 on a 64-bit machine running a 32-bit process. It should get the processor architecture, not the executable architecture, unless that is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
switch (typeof(string).Assembly.GetName().ProcessorArchitecture) {
    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.X86:
        // '$(Platform)' == 'x86'
        break;
    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.Amd64:
        // '$(Platform)' == 'x64'
        break;
    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.MSIL:
        // MacBook Pro with M1 Pro (from comment)
        break;
    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.None:
        // ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly
        break;
    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.Arm:
        // Unknown
        break;
}
```

However `case *.Arm:` isn't tested yet.

Comment: This returned `ProcessorArchitecture.MSIL` on my MacBook Pro with M1 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx) CodeProject article could help? It uses the ManagementObjectSearcher in the System.Management namespace to search for hardware info.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on why you want to know, you might find that checking the size of the IntPtr structure is the easiest way.

Comment: I like the way Anonymous Coward thinks!

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user perhaps?

Just kidding of course... I think WMI is what you would use for that. But maybe there is some other way as well?

If you go for WMI then LinqToWmi could be of use. I tried it out once, and it seemed pretty straight forward =) -> http://www.codeplex.com/linq2wmi

Answer (score 0):

This seems the simplest to me:

```
System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
```

Comment: it's available in .NET 4.0 while the question is about .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way:

If the operating system is Linux, pinvoke the libc-syscall uname, where you will have the processor in the Machine-field.

If the OS is Windows, check if System.IntPtr.Size * 8 = 64, then it's 64 bit. 
If it isn't 64-Bit, you check if IsWow64Process exists, and if it exists, and the process is Wow64, then it's x86-64, else it's x86-32.

This one is reliable. 
Checking the processor-architecture environment variables is not.

Code:

```
namespace RamMonitorPrototype
{


    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202696/155077
    //[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    //unsafe internal struct Utsname_internal
    //{
    //    public fixed byte sysname[65];
    //    public fixed byte nodename[65];
    //    public fixed byte release[65];
    //    public fixed byte version[65];
    //    public fixed byte machine[65];
    //    public fixed byte domainname[65];
    //}


    public class Utsname
    {
        public string SysName; // char[65]
        public string NodeName; // char[65]
        public string Release; // char[65]
        public string Version; // char[65]
        public string Machine; // char[65]
        public string DomainName; // char[65]

        public void Print()
        {
            System.Console.Write("SysName:\t");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.SysName); // Linux 

            System.Console.Write("NodeName:\t");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.NodeName); // System.Environment.MachineName

            System.Console.Write("Release:\t");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.Release); // Kernel-version

            System.Console.Write("Version:\t");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.Version); // #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019

            System.Console.Write("Machine:\t");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.Machine); // x86_64

            System.Console.Write("DomainName:\t");
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.DomainName); // (none)
        }


    }


    // https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/microsoft/win32/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs
    // https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Environment.Windows.cs
    public class DetermineOsBitness
    {
        private const string Kernel32 = "kernel32.dll";



        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "uname", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int uname_syscall(System.IntPtr buf);

        // https://github.com/jpobst/Pinta/blob/master/Pinta.Core/Managers/SystemManager.cs
        public static Utsname Uname()
        {
            Utsname uts = null;
            System.IntPtr buf = System.IntPtr.Zero;

            buf = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8192);
            // This is a hacktastic way of getting sysname from uname ()
            if (uname_syscall(buf) == 0)
            {
                uts = new Utsname();
                uts.SysName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buf);

                long bufVal = buf.ToInt64();
                uts.NodeName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 1 * 65));
                uts.Release = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 2 * 65));
                uts.Version = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 3 * 65));
                uts.Machine = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 4 * 65));
                uts.DomainName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 5 * 65));

                if (buf != System.IntPtr.Zero)
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
            } // End if (uname_syscall(buf) == 0) 

            return uts;
        } // End Function Uname



        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(Kernel32, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
        [System.Runtime.Versioning.ResourceExposure(System.Runtime.Versioning.ResourceScope.Machine)]
        private static extern System.IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string modName);


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(Kernel32, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        [System.Runtime.Versioning.ResourceExposure(System.Runtime.Versioning.ResourceScope.None)]
        private static extern System.IntPtr GetProcAddress(System.IntPtr hModule, string methodName);


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(Kernel32, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool IsWow64Process(
             [System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid hProcess,
             [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out, System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] out bool wow64Process
        );


        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        private static bool DoesWin32MethodExist(string moduleName, string methodName)
        {
            System.IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(moduleName);

            if (hModule == System.IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(hModule != System.IntPtr.Zero, "GetModuleHandle failed.  Dll isn't loaded?");
                return false;
            }

            System.IntPtr functionPointer = GetProcAddress(hModule, methodName);
            return (functionPointer != System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        public static bool Is64BitOperatingSystem()
        {
            if (System.IntPtr.Size * 8 == 64)
                return true;

            if (!DoesWin32MethodExist(Kernel32, "IsWow64Process"))
                return false;

            bool isWow64;

            using(Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle safeHandle = new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, true))
            {
                IsWow64Process(safeHandle, out isWow64);
            }
            return isWow64;
        }

        // This doesn't work reliably
        public static string GetProcessorArchitecture()
        {
            string strProcessorArchitecture = null;

            try
            {
                strProcessorArchitecture = System.Convert.ToString(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"));

                switch (typeof(string).Assembly.GetName().ProcessorArchitecture)
                {
                    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.X86:
                        strProcessorArchitecture = "x86";
                        break;
                    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.Amd64:
                        strProcessorArchitecture = "x86";
                        break;
                    case System.Reflection.ProcessorArchitecture.Arm:
                        strProcessorArchitecture = "ARM";
                        break;
                }

                bool is64bit = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"));

                if (is64bit)
                    strProcessorArchitecture += "-64";
                else
                    strProcessorArchitecture += "-32";
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                strProcessorArchitecture = ex.Message;
            }

            return strProcessorArchitecture;
        } // End Function GetProcessorArchitecture


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:    `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`

for example: `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? "win-x64" : "win-x86"`

it's applied to **.NET Framework 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8, 4.8.1**

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should avoid heavy bloat like WMI  and LINQ.. and you'll have to eventually, to get more info as you go along, none of which are satisfied by bloated apis and frameworks.

Just invoke a dll that calls and extracts CPUID info. C++/CLI or pinvoke would do and get all the info you need on the vendor. First you need to see whether the instruction is supported (99% of the time it is).

To get quickly up and running is to check the intel site for wincpuid sample and extract the piece from cpuid.h from there.  There are only 2 vendors and one is good with memory latency and the other one isn't (like native vs managed code). So you'll have issues with Mono on other architectures etc (who doesn't btw). As for x64 you already know it or just get the corflags (its there already and killing your customer hard drive with .NET distribution )..

(http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-detects-ia-32-and-x64-platform-cpu-characteristics/)

Comment: Thank you for already voicing the thought I had (which elicited a groan) when I read the suggestion of using WMI.

Comment: Your link to intel.com is now dead.

Answer (score -4):

Here's what I did:

```
public static bool Isx86()
{
    return (Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%").Length == 0);
}
```

If you're on 64 bit architecture you'll have two program file env variables. If you're on x86, you'll only have the one.

Comment: Ugly, if all you care about is 32bit vs 64 bit aka x86 vs x64 just use the following BCL property Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem