# How can I check the bitness of my OS using Java? (J2SE, not os.arch)

Tags: java, operating-system

I'm developing a software application that checks what kind of software you have installed, but in order to do so, I must know if the OS is a 32 bit or a 64 bit OS.

I tried System.getProperty("os.arch"); but then I read that this command only shows us the bitness of the JDK/JRE, not the OS itself. If you could tell me how to know which OS is being used (Windows 7, Mac OS, Ubuntu, etc...) that would be simply awesome.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what I thought, but then I saw this link, you might want to check it out: http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/javas-osarch-system-property-is-the-bitness-of-the-jre-not-the-operating-system.html tell me what you think

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Should be available on all platforms, see the Java [System Properties Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for more information.

**But** 64 bit Windows platforms will lie to the JVM if it is a 32 bit JVM. Actually 64 bit Windows will lie to any 32 bit process about the environment to help old 32 bit programs work properly on a 64 bit OS. Read the [MSDN article about WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

As a result of WOW64, a 32 bit JVM calling `System.getProperty("os.arch")` will return "x86". If you want to get the *real* architecture of the underlying OS on Windows, use the following logic:

```
String arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
String wow64Arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");

String realArch = arch != null && arch.endsWith("64")
                  || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64")
                      ? "64" : "32";
```

See also:

[HOWTO: Detect Process Bitness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/howto-detect-process-bitness.aspx)

[Why %processor_architecture% always returns x86 instead of AMD64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738985/why-processor-architecture-always-returns-x86-instead-of-amd64)

[Detect whether current Windows version is 32 bit or 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601089/detect-whether-current-windows-version-is-32-bit-or-64-bit)

Comment: I get NPE's on the realArch line on mac osx :(

Comment: Works better than our previous implementation.  Thanks!

Comment: I want to apologize, all this time I though I had your answer selected as the correct answer! But it's done now (:

Comment: How about MacOS and Linux?

Comment: @user7485... I think os.arch is always the bitness of the JRE, not the OS.  e.g. [System.getProperty("os.arch") in java code yields i386 os architecture, but my ubuntu is actually x86\_64. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60730849).  It's not Windows that lies to Java in this case, it's that `os.arch` means the bitness of the JRE.

Comment: For MacOS, if arch & wow64arch are null, use arch = System.getProperty( "os.arch" );

Comment: in my case the command prompt showing the following value
`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
AMD64`

but `String procArch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
         System.out.println(procArch);` 
is showing still x86 only. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

os.arch is NOT the bitness of the OS, beware of this solution! http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/javas-osarch-system-property-is-the-bitness-of-the-jre-not-the-operating-system.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without getting plattform specific.
Have a look at the last post on [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/189614-detect-os-architecture-not-jvm/) page (the solution there is plattform specific).

The property `os.name` gives you the name of the used operating system, `os.version` the version.

Answer (score -2):

You can check by calling

```
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
```

This line returns 32 or 64 which identifies if the JVM is either 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: System properties beginning with `sun.` aren't standard.

Comment: Further, the OP is about the OS, not the JVM