# JAVA function to detect CPU size

Tags: java

How to write a function in java to detect whether your operating system is running on a 32 bit processor or 64 bit processor ? One answer i found in the internet was this 
Shift 1 into an int until the int flips to 0 and count how many places you were able to shift over.
But i am not able to understand the solution.

Comment: The solution you describe with an `int` will not work in Java, because in Java (unlike in C or C++) an `int` is always 32 bits, no matter if the JVM and operating you are running on is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

System.getProperty ("os.arch");

On my PC returns amd64.

Btw,That is really a popular gotcha.

Article by Oracle:
[Beware when detecting the 32 or 64 bit OS](https://blogs.oracle.com/DieterDeramoudt/entry/beware_when_detecting_32_and)

Please note, the os.arch property will only give you the architecture of the JRE, not of the underlying os.

If you install a 32 bit jre on a 64 bit system, System.getProperty("os.arch") will return x86

In order to actually determine the underlying architecture, you will need to write some native code. See this post for more info (and a link to sample native code).

If you're using windows then this will be the exact solution for you:

```
boolean is64bit = false;
```

`if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {`

```
is64bit = (System.getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)") != null);
```

`} else {`

```
is64bit = (System.getProperty("os.arch").indexOf("64") != -1);
```

}`

The processor architecture can be detected by using the code below:

```
    String arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
String wow64Arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");

String realArch = arch.endsWith("64")
                  || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64")
                      ? "64" : "32";
System.out.println(realArch);
```

Comment: This won't work if you run it within a x32 bit JVM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748673/how-can-i-check-the-bitness-of-my-os-using-java-j2se-not-os-arch for more details

Answer (score 0):

**In native languages, such as C and C++:**

- Your code is executed directly on the CPU.
- You have a direct access to memory, which is the primary reason for which the language also provides the ability to determine the size of different types (using the `sizeof` operator).

**In non-native languages, such as Java and C#:**

- Your code is executed on a VM (which is essentially a CPU-emulation program).
- You do not have a direct access to memory, hence the language does not really need to provide the ability to determine the size of different types.

So whereas in C and C++ you could use `sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT` in order to determine the width of your processor's memory-bus, you cannot do the same in Java and C#.

The solution you mention, probably assumes that the size of `int` in Java is 32 bits on a 32-bit VM, and 64-bits on a 64-bit VM.

Even if this assumption is true, it will indicate **the type of the VM** that you are running on, and **not the type of the CPU** that you are running on.

Now, assuming that the size of `int` in Java is indeed 32 bits on a 32-bit VM and 64-bits on a 64-bit VM, here is the logic behind the solution:

```
int n = 1; // n == 0x0000000000000001 (iteration #0)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000002 (iteration #1)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000004 (iteration #2)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000008 (iteration #3)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000010 (iteration #4)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000020 (iteration #5)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000040 (iteration #6)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000080 (iteration #7)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000100 (iteration #8)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000200 (iteration #9)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000400 (iteration #10)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000800 (iteration #11)
...
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x1000000000000000 (iteration #60)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x2000000000000000 (iteration #61)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x4000000000000000 (iteration #62)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x8000000000000000 (iteration #63)
n <<= 1;   // n == 0x0000000000000000 (iteration #64)
```

On a 32-bit system, `n` will run between 0x00000001 and 0x80000000 before it becomes 0x00000000 (after 32 iterations).

But if the assumption above is correct, then you might as well just do it in a single bit-shift operation:

```
int n = 0x80000000;
if (n<<1 == 0)
    ; // 32-bit system
else
    ; // 64-bit system
```

As a side note, I have to say that I doubt this assumption to begin with. On a 32-bit VM, the size of `int` is 32 bits and the size of `long` is 64 bits. So what would be the size of `long` on a 64-bit VM then???