# How to determine 32-bit OS or 64-bit OS from Java application

Tags: java

I know how to check whether the JVM is 32 or 64-bit is running on a current Machine using java program.
But is there any possibility to know if the OS on current machine is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Please let me know how to determine using Java Program.

Comment: You may want to check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run

```
System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

to retrieve the systems architecture. My Windows 64bit system will return `amd64` as `os.arch` value.

Comment: Well... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html states `"os.arch" Operating system architecture `

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Should be available on all platforms, see the Java System Properties Tutorial for more information.

But 64 bit Windows platforms will lie to the JVM if it is a 32 bit JVM. Actually 64 bit Windows will lie to any 32 bit process about the environment to help old 32 bit programs work properly on a 64 bit OS. Read the MSDN article about WOW64 for more information.

As a result of WOW64, a 32 bit JVM calling System.getProperty("os.arch") will return "x86". If you want to get the real architecture of the underlying OS on Windows, use the following logic:

```
String arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
String wow64Arch = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");

String realArch = arch != null && arch.endsWith("64")
                  || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64")
                      ? "64" : "32";
```

This question was answered by [ChrisH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71109/chrish).

Comment: Here is the link to the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748673/how-can-i-check-the-bitness-of-my-os-using-java-j2se-not-os-arch/5940770#5940770