# System.getProperty("os.arch") in java code yields i386 os architecture, but my ubuntu is actually x86_64. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, java, 64-bit, cpu-architecture

Can somebody briefly explain why outputs of `System.getProperty("os.arch")` in java and result of the command `uname -u` in terminal show me different results? As I understand i386 stands for 32 bit architecture, and x86_64 for 64 bit. I'm totally confused by that...

Comment: You might have 32 bit Java installed on a 64 bit system.

Comment: `os.arch` is the bitness / architecture the JRE was compiled for, not the kernel of the system that it's running on.