# Batch to exe not working when compiled

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

my problem is that when I convert a .bat file to a compiled .exe file using the software "Bat to exe converter v1.6" does not work at 100%.
The .bat works at 100% when I use it, but not the .exe.

The .bat file in question has two conditional expressions, but the processor architecture's one is not working:

> rem the first is checking that, and its working 100%
>
> > IF %SistemaOp% == XP (goto winxp) else (goto winseven)

```
:winxp

    echo xp
```

rem this is the part that it's NOT working. It never goes to 64 bit part

```
    IF  %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (goto winxp86) else (goto winxp64)
    :winxp86
            echo xp 32 bit
    :winxp64
            echo xp 64 bit
:winseven
    echo seven
```

rem this is the other part that it's NOT working. It never goes to 64 bit part

```
    IF  %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (goto winseven86) else (goto winseven64)
    :winseven86
    echo seven 32 bit
    :winseven64
    echo seven 64 bit
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the exe is a 32-bit executable, so it cannot tell if the processor is 64-bit.

Comment: Related question that may help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738985/why-processor-architecture-always-returns-x86-instead-of-amd64.

Comment: ok, so how could I compile a .bat to .exe in 64-bit application?

Answer (score 0):

It is probable your converter i use [Advanced bat to exe](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) It is a good compiler and it also adds it own advanced commands. Give it a go. It does 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: I tried with Advanced bat to exe Converter 2.83 but it don't seems to appear that 64 bit option.

Comment: It does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was changing the %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% part to this:

> @echo off
>
> SET ARCHITECT=HELLO
>   reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v
>
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  | find "ARCH" | FINDSTR /L "86" > NUL
>
> IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (SET ARCHITECT=32 bit) ELSE (SET ARCHITECT=64 bit)
>
> echo %ARCHITECT%
>
> pause