# Is it possible to definitively tell if a user is using laptop?

Tags: c++, system

I need to be able to tell if a user is using a laptop or not, using c++ code.
There were a few suggestions (such as checking if there is a battery) here:
[How can I tell if a user is using a laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837152/how-can-i-tell-if-a-user-is-using-a-laptop)
and here:
[Detect if application is running on laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849447/detect-if-application-is-running-on-laptop)
but none of them seems definitive.
Edit: the os is windows.

Comment: Since this probably has different answers depending on the OS, you might want to specify what OS you're targeting.

Comment: I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849447/detect-if-application-is-running-on-laptop)

Comment: You can always check the output of querying the touchpad. Unlikely to have one unless on a laptop. For Linux see `libinput list-devices` [libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) and also [Touchpad Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) for ideas of what to check.

Comment: Why do you need to know laptop or not? How about tablet? Notebook? Mouseless kiosk? Try to avoid the trap of an XY-problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if a user is using a laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837152/how-can-i-tell-if-a-user-is-using-a-laptop)

Comment: Why do You need to know the type of device? What do You want to do with this information?