# C# sizeof object pointer (SAFE context)

Tags: c#, pointers, 32bit-64bit, sizeof

Ok while sizeof(Myenum) and sizeof(int) works, I would like to use sizeof(object), but I don't want the size of the object, but the size of pointer... only for portability reason, I need to know if is a 64 bit pointer or 32 bit pointer, I can avoid using sizeof if is ok with conditional compilation, but I don't know if there are constants to check if we are on a 32 bit system instead of 64 bit

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying the CPU architecture type using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767613/identifying-the-cpu-architecture-type-using-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Mh the problem is, while the context is different (I want size of something), it involves cpu detection, so I think that if someone will search for sizeof(object) it's better if he finds this question, so he will not open a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IntPtr.Size`.

Reference : [Simple way to check if you're on a 64-bit machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kstanton/archive/2004/04/20/116923.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is platform-specific. That is, an instance of this type is expected to be 32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on 64-bit hardware and operating systems.

The IntPtr type is a pointer, found it at [IntPtr Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).