# how to check type of processor architcture runtime

Tags: c#, x86-64, itanium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identifying the CPU architecture type using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767613/identifying-the-cpu-architecture-type-using-c-sharp)

my program is using diffrent assemblies  for its final part.The problem is that amd and intelx64 assemblies are not fully compatible. Its is for an compiler im working on.

Answer (score 0):

you could use exception handling, using try and catch.

```
try
{
    // intel assembly
}
catch
{
    // amd assembly
}
```

Comment: that actually might not work very well since some of the assembly might run before an error occurs. it was just an idea