# Get uname release field from C# in .NET Core on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, posix, pinvoke

I'm trying to get the output of `uname -r` in C# in .NET Core 2.2 running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm writing this with performance in mind, so have been trying to use a P/Invoke to achieve it.

The [`uname(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) docs indicate I need to pass a struct in with the relevant sized fields. After playing with a lot of variations, I came up with:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe internal struct Utsname
{
    public fixed byte sysname[65];

    public fixed byte nodename[65];

    public fixed byte release[65];

    public fixed byte version[65];

    public fixed byte machine[65];
}

public static class Main
{
    [DllImport("libc.so.6", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int uname(ref Utsname buf);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bs = new byte[65];
        unsafe
        {
            var buf = new utsname();
            uname(ref buf);
            Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)buf.release, bs, 0, 65);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bs));
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but moving it into a wrapper function like:

```cs
public static class Main
{

...

    public static string GetUnameRelease()
    {
        var bs = new List<byte>();
        unsafe
        {
            var buf = new utsname();
            uname(ref buf);

            int i = 0;
            byte* p = buf.release;
            while (i < 65 && *p != 0)
            {
                bs.Add(*p);
                p++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bs.ToArray());
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetUnameRelease());
    }
}
```

Seems to cause it to fail. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. It fails silently, presumably due to a segfault, although I'm not sure where/how to get a trace of that.

#### Other struct marshalling methods I've tried

I also tried a few other ways to get the struct back.

The simplest seemed to be the `string` fields with fixed-length values (but I assume this fails because the caller needs to allocate mutable fields for the callee to set):

```cs
internal struct Utsname
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 65)]
    public string sysname;

    ...
}
```

Or a simple `byte` array:

```cs
internal struct Utsname
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 65)]
    public byte[] sysname;

    ...
}
```

In this case, I assume the problem is something to do with the In/Out calling convention when passing a managed array into the call.

I tried using `out` instead of `ref` to simplify the P/Invoke as well, but I get the impression `uname()` expects the caller to allocate the memory before the call.

I also tried using the `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes, but not sure what the defaults are or how using them would change things.

#### Writing an external C library to wrap the call

I also wrote a small C library to wrap the call to make the calling convention easier to handle:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

char *get_uname_release()
{
    struct utsname buf;

    uname(&buf);

    size_t len = strlen(buf.release);

    char *release = malloc(len * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(release, buf.release);

    return release;
}
```

I compiled this with `gcc -shared -o libget_uname.so -fPIC get_uname.c` and put it next to the main managed DLL.

Calling this was much easier, with just:

```cs
public static class Main
{
    ...

    [DllImport("libget_uname.so", EntryPoint = "uname_get_release", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal static extern string GetUnameRelease();
}
```

This seemed to work every time I used it.

But I'm averse to including a native library in code, if it might be possible to just P/Invoke directly instead.

#### Using a `Process` call instead

The other obvious simple choice would just be to call the `uname` coreutil as a subprocess:

```cs
public static class Main
{
    ...

    public static string GetUnameRelease()
    {
        var unameProc = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "uname",
                Arguments = "-r",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        unameProc.Start();
        unameProc.WaitForExit();
        return unameProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

But I was hoping to avoid the overhead of a subprocess... Perhaps it's not so bad on Linux and just worth doing?

But I've spent a while looking into the PInvoke now, so I would like to know if it's possible.

#### Questions

So my questions are:

- What's the best (fastest reliable) way to get the `release` field from `uname` from C#?
- How would I P/Invoke the `uname()` syscall in libc reliably to get the `utsname` struct back?

Comment: Also, I'm aware the buffer length of 65 is implementation defined, but I'm not sure how to get around that, since I can't rely on the implementation to define the struct for me. Would be interested in how to get around that...

Comment: Your "move into a wrapper function" also includes using a different way of extracting the data. Have you tried moving *the exact working code* to a different method instead? (The one that copies the byte array before extracting the text.) I would also note that you probably don't want a string that treats the whole byte array as text - you probably want to find the first 0 in the array and only decode the bytes leading up to that.

Comment: Good point - I've updated the wrapper function with a safer `strcpy`-like implementation. Following it through on the debugger, the program silently crashes at the `uname(ref buf)` call.

Comment: You've still got differences between the version that works and the version that doesn't. One step at a time: if you *just* move the working code out of the `Main` method into a separate method, does that really still break things? (I can't see why just changing which method is calling it would do that.) But then I wonder if you're showing us the real code... the code you've shown doesn't compile due to a difference in casing. I would personally remove the aspects about other processes and the native library - stick to asking a very specific question.

Comment: (It would be worth *mentioning* the other approaches with a sentence for each, but at the moment they're more of a distraction.)

Comment: To avoid the issue with getting the right structure size, which can vary with releases of the kernel you should probably read the data from the filesystem. /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease will give the same result. From a performance perspective, this is not a real disk file, but a virtual file that exposes kernel info so it is essentially just reading from memory.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText("/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease");` will give you the OS release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working when you move the code to a function is that your structure does not include the `domainname` member, so when you call `uname` it is clobbering memory beyond the memory you allocated for your structure.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe internal struct Utsname
{
        public fixed byte sysname[65];
        public fixed byte nodename[65];
        public fixed byte release[65];
        public fixed byte version[65];
        public fixed byte machine[65];
        public fixed byte domainname[65];
}

public static class Program
{
        [DllImport("libc.so.6", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern int uname(ref Utsname buf);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(GetUnameRelease());
        }

        static unsafe string GetUnameRelease()
        {
                Utsname buf;
                uname(ref buf);
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)buf.release);
        }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I saw the field, but all the documentation had it wrapped in an ifdef -- couldn't get a straight answer as to whether it was a real field. I tried putting it in a few times, but should have persisted. Thanks!

Also, will follow your advice on reading from `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease`.

Answer (score 1):

Version that doesn't require **unsafe** code nor **Mono**:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace UnameTest
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    internal struct Utsname
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 65)]
        public byte[] sysname;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 65)]
        public byte[] nodename;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 65)]
        public byte[] release;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 65)]
        public byte[] version;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 65)]
        public byte[] machine;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 65)]
        public byte[] domainname;
    }

    public static class Uts
    {
        [DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "uname", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern int uname(ref Utsname buf);

        public static void PrintUtsname()
        {
            Utsname buf = new Utsname();
            uname(ref buf);

            Console.WriteLine($"Utsname:");
            Console.WriteLine($"---------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"sysname: {GetString(buf.sysname)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"nodename: {GetString(buf.nodename)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"release: {GetString(buf.release)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"version: {GetString(buf.version)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"machine: {GetString(buf.machine)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"domainname: {GetString(buf.domainname)}");
        }


        private static string GetString(in byte[] data)
        {
            var pos = Array.IndexOf<byte>(data, 0);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, (pos < 0) ? data.Length : pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that doesn't require unsafe code:

```
public class Utsname
{
    public string SysName; // char[65]
    public string NodeName; // char[65]
    public string Release; // char[65]
    public string Version; // char[65]
    public string Machine; // char[65]
    public string DomainName; // char[65]

    public void Print()
    {
        System.Console.Write("SysName:\t");
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.SysName);

        System.Console.Write("NodeName:\t");
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.NodeName);

        System.Console.Write("Release:\t");
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.Release);

        System.Console.Write("Version:\t");
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.Version);

        System.Console.Write("Machine:\t");
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.Machine);

        System.Console.Write("DomainName:\t");
        System.Console.WriteLine(this.DomainName);


        Mono.Unix.Native.Utsname buf;
        Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.uname(out buf);

        System.Console.WriteLine(buf.sysname);
        System.Console.WriteLine(buf.nodename);
        System.Console.WriteLine(buf.release);
        System.Console.WriteLine(buf.version);
        System.Console.WriteLine(buf.machine);
        System.Console.WriteLine(buf.domainname);
    }


}


[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "uname", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int uname_syscall(System.IntPtr buf);

// https://github.com/jpobst/Pinta/blob/master/Pinta.Core/Managers/SystemManager.cs
private static Utsname Uname()
{
    Utsname uts = null;
    System.IntPtr buf = System.IntPtr.Zero;

    buf = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8192);
    // This is a hacktastic way of getting sysname from uname ()
    if (uname_syscall(buf) == 0)
    {
        uts = new Utsname();
        uts.SysName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buf);

        long bufVal = buf.ToInt64();
        uts.NodeName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 1 * 65));
        uts.Release = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 2 * 65));
        uts.Version = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 3 * 65));
        uts.Machine = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 4 * 65));
        uts.DomainName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new System.IntPtr(bufVal + 5 * 65));

        if (buf != System.IntPtr.Zero)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
    } // End if (uname_syscall(buf) == 0) 

    return uts;
} // End Function Uname
```